# How do I find which team has a piece of Gear equipped?

Tags: pokemon-masters

In *Pokémon Masters EX*, I have a piece of 1* Gear that I'd like to get rid of, as I now have the equivalent 3* Gear of that type. However, the Gear is showing as "On Team" and won't let me exchange it:

[image]

I have no idea which team this Gear is equipped to in order to be able to unequip it, and I have no idea how to find out. So... how do I find out?

Comment: I fear you have to check every team to find out, and also the preset teams